# Finding new IP in a file

Tags: python, ironpython, ip-address, compare

I have a file of IP addresses called "IPs". When I parse a new IP from my logs, I'd like to see if the new IP is already in file IPs, before I add it. I know how to add the new IP to the file, but I'm having trouble seeing if the new IP is already in the file.

```
!/usr/bin/python
from IPy import IP
IP = IP('192.168.1.2')
#f=open(IP('IPs', 'r'))  #This line doesn't work
f=open('IPs', 'r')    # this one doesn't work 
for line in f:
    if IP == line:
       print "Found " +IP +" before"
f.close()
```

In the file "IPs", each IP address is on it's own line. As such:

```
222.111.222.111
222.111.222.112
```

Also tried to put the file IPs in to an array, but not having good luck with that either.
Any ideas?

Thank you,

Gary

Comment: This should probably have a Python tag.

Comment: Hmmm, the question to this issue is misleading, you seem to be having trouble with Python file access, not with doing a file search

Comment: It sounds like the file open isn't finding the file called `IPs` - are you sure its not `IPs.txt` or similar?  What is the exact error you get?

Comment: You didn't give any error message or tell what doesn't work as expected, could you be more precise?

Comment: Not really sure, but don't think I need a file extension.
I'd like to get a IP from my log file and add it to a list of IPs I already have. But I don't want to add it to the list if it's already on the list. So i have to search through the list to make sure the new IP isn't already listed.

Comment: Error I get is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "open.py", line 8, in <module>
    if IP == line:
  File "/var/lib/python-support/python2.5/IPy.py", line 661, in __cmp__
    if self._prefixlen < other.prefixlen():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'prefixlen'

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):<br>
  File "open.py", line 8, in <module><br>
    if IP == line:<br>
  File "/var/lib/python-support/python2.5/IPy.py", line 661, in __cmp__<br>
    if self._prefixlen < other.prefixlen():<br>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'prefixlen'<br>

Comment: Sorry for the format of the error layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
iplist = []

# With takes care of all the fun file handling stuff (closing, etc.)
with open('ips.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        iplist.append(line.strip())   # Gets rid of the newlines at the end

# Change the above to this for Python versions < 2.6
f = open('ips.txt', 'r')
for line in f:
    iplist.append(line.strip())
f.close()

newip = '192.168.1.2'

if newip not in iplist:
    f = open('ips.txt', 'a') # append mode, please
    f.write(newip+'\n')
```

Now you have your IPs in a list (iplist) and you can easily add your newip to it `iplist.append(newip)` or do anything else you please.

---

Edit:

Some excellent books for learning Python:
If you're worried about programming being difficult, there's a book that's geared towards kids, but I honestly found it both easy-to-digest and informative.
[Snake Wrangling for Kids](http://www.briggs.net.nz/log/writing/snake-wrangling-for-kids/)

Another great resource for learning Python is [How to Think Like a Computer Scientist](http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/).

There's also the [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/) on the official Python website. It's a little dry compared to the previous ones.

Alan Gauld, one of the foremost contributors to the tutor@python.org mailing list has [this tutorial](http://www.alan-g.me.uk/) that's really good and also is adapted to Python 3. He also includes some other languages for comparison.

If you want a good dead-tree book, I've heard that [Core Python Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132269937) by Wesley Chun is a really good resource. He also contributes to the python tutor list every so often.

The [tutor list](http://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/tutor) is another good place to learn about python - reading, replying, and asking your own questions. I actually learned most of my python by trying to answer as many of the questions I could. I'd seriously recommend subscribing to the tutor list if you want to learn Python.

Comment: Using a set instead of a list would make lookups faster.

Comment: Wayne, Your code works the way I needed, so THANK YOU!!!  But I think i'm giving up and stay with Bash/grep. The box this python script is going on is running Python 2.4, it's a production box. My machine is running Python 2.6.5.  The admin doesn't have plans to upgrade any time soon.  SO SORRY I didn't mention this before, didn't think it mattered but it does.

Comment: Ah, yes. At least if you use `with` - I'll put up the similar code for  < 2.6

Comment: and thanks for the "# Gets rid of the newlines at the end" comment cause i wasn't sure what line.strip was for.

Comment: BINGO! That works!!! THANKS!! I understand everything in your code, but i'd like to read more about "iplist.append(line.strip())". Can you give me any key phrases I can google and learn? Know of any good books for (you might be surprised by this) a noob non-programmer?
Thanks Gary

Comment: considering how you use it, why do you even try to load those in a list or hash or set? if you going to read the whole file, do the check in the loop!

Comment: One of the best places to look is in the python docs. Take a look at the strings: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods and lists: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html I'd also recommend ipython as a great tool for learning: http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/ I thought I had posted a list of some good Python books, but I can't seem to find the post. I guess I'll just add them to my answer.

Comment: @EnTerr - That's how I'd do it if I wasn't worried about anything else: `found = False; if newip == line.strip(): found = True; break; if not found: #write line`, but the OP did mention putting the IPs in a list, presumably to do something else with. But I didn't mention that, so good catch.

Comment: @Wayne Werner: there is more pythonic way to do it if you use `for .. else`, see my code below. +1 for the plentitude of helpful links

Answer (score 2):

It's a trivial code but i think it is short and pretty in Python, so here is how i'd write it:

```
ip = '192.168.1.2'

lookFor = ip + '\n'
f = open('ips.txt', 'a+')
for line in f:
    if line == lookFor:
        print 'found', ip, 'before.'
        break
else:
    print ip, 'not found, adding to file.'
    print >>f, ip
f.close()
```

It opens the file in append mode, reads and if not found (that's what `else` to a `for` does - executes if the loop exited normally and not via break) - appends the new IP. ta-da!

Now will be ineffective when you have a lot of IPs. Here is another hack i thought of, it uses 1 file per 1 IP as a flag:

```
import os

ip = '192.168.1.2'

fname = ip + '.ip'
if os.access(fname, os.F_OK):
    print 'found', ip, 'before.'
else:
    print ip, 'not found, registering.'
    open(fname, 'w').close()
```

Why is this fast? Because most file systems these days (except FAT on Windows but NTFS is ok) organize the list of files in a directory into a B-tree structure, so checking for a file existence is a fast operation O(log N) instead of enumerating whole list.

(I am not saying this is practical - depends on amount of IPs you expect to see and your sysadmin benevolence.)

Comment: Great idea with separate files! Just tested with 65K IPs (192.168.*.*). Log parsing is done for 9414 us, whereas file system check takes 50 us (average of 3 tests, EXT4). Nearly 200 times faster! Fetch an upvote (:

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need this IP thing? Use simple strings.

```
!#/usr/bin/env python

ip = "192.168.1.2" + "\n" ### Fixed -- see comments
f = open('IPs', 'r')
for line in f:
    if line.count(ip):
       print "Found " + ip
f.close()
```

Besides, this looks more like a task for `grep` and friends.

Comment: I did this in grep already and it works. But a co-worker suggested I learn python and I'm like python.<br>
About your code, if you put 192.168.1.22 in file IPs, this code says "Found 192.168.1.2", and that's why you need the "from IPy import IP" thing.

Comment: there is a bug indeed but it's easy to fix: replace `line.count(ip)` with `line==ip` and change the definition above to `ip = "192.168.1.2" + "\n"` (better to do that once outside the loop than do strip() or concatenation multiple times inside)

Comment: Yes, my bad, thanks for fixing. `count()` was used to ignore leading spaces, if any. EnTerr's suggestion with `+ "\n"` is the right way to go if you are sure there will be no leading spaces before IPs. Otherwise, consider using regular expressions.